# Bootstrap Datepicker shows wrong calendar at first time

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap Datepicker to place an date input field in my HTML document. I use the following code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="manifest-date" class="calender form-control" placeholder="M-d-yy" id="manifest-date" value="{{$currentDate}}" data-date-format="M-dd-yy"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var d1 = $('input[id="manifest-date"][name="manifest-date"]').datepicker({autoclose:true}).datepicker({"setDate":new Date(), format: 'M-dd-yy'});
});
```

When I reload the page and click on the calendar, the calendar shows 1 February 2022 instead of the current date. My locale is set to the correct date and time. So every time I have to switch the calendar from 2022 to 2018. This is only happening when I change the date format in HTML. It shows the correct calendar for 'mm/dd/yyyy'

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please change code to $(document).ready(function($){
            var d1 = $('input[id="manifest-date"][name="manifest-date"]').datepicker({autoclose:true,setDate:new Date(), format: 'M-dd-yy'});

Comment: Changed. But issue is still there

Comment: Which date you getting in your value="{{$currentDate}}" ?

Comment: Can you try this? https://jsfiddle.net/acq7t97c/4318/ I don't see there is any problem

Comment: @Kishan I get Oct-22-18

Comment: @Justcode I need the Oct-1-18 format in the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem is in your jQuery function. Use it as follows:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({format : 'M-dd-yy', autoclose: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `M-d-yy`, I'd recommend you use the format `mm-dd-yyyy` as stated in the documentation.

You can take a look at the Bootstrap datepicker docs here => https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration